# print struct pointer c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to print the outcome of the function below

```
void add_votes(struct votes* v1, struct votes* v2) {
    v1->men += v2->men;
    v1->women += v2->women;
}
```

With this set of code

```
add_votes(all, michigan);
    printf("all->men: %d\n", &(all->men);
```

Here are all needed variables and structure

```
struct votes {
    int men;
    int women;
};
struct votes *michigan = {200, 300};
struct votes *all = {0, 0};
```

I tried placing an & before the cast in the printf but after a second printf it displays the address of the pointer
and when I print it without a & it doesn't display nothing

If it’s supposed to be a pointer how should I do it
And if I remove the & from the print it says a series of number I guess the address but I need the value
It says something like 1303720 when I need it to be 200 or something like that

Comment: Should just be `printf("all->men: %d\n", all->men);`  You don't care about the address at all.  Note, though, that you are not correctly initializing your pointer variables; they have to point to something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable declarations are wrong. They should be structures, not pointers.

```
struct votes michigan = {200, 300};
struct votes all = {0, 0};
```

Then you pass the addresses of the structures to the function:

```
add_votes(&all, &michigan);
printf("all.men: %d\n", all.men);
```

Comment: Ok but how is the function add_votes going to look if I make it all normal structures it's not assigning values

Comment: `add_votes` doesn't change. It's receiving pointers to these structures, so it updates the contents.